# HOW DO YOU CHOOSE WHICH DESIGN PATTERN TO USE?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, architecture

> How would you decide which design pattern to use?

I am asked the above question in at-least 2 different interviews .Apparently I am not the only one.Somebody else posted the same question on glassdoor.

http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/How-would-you-decide-which-design-pattern-to-use-QTN_47521.htm

Any thoughts/suggestions/comments on how to answer that question ?

Comment: The Visitor pattern, obviously.

Comment: What is the problem that needs solving? Did I miss something? Or is that the whole question?

Comment: It really depends on the use case. There is no one size fits all.

Comment: More seriously: this question, stated as-is, without any context, is totally unanswerable.

Comment: I like the pink with polka dots pattern.  That's my answer. Did I get the job? (er... how exactly did you get those tags for that question?)

Comment: I answered that question saying it depends on what specs I have.I said I recently used repository pattern because the project is CRUD  intensive.I went on to explain what repository pattern is .They came back to same question on how would I chose a design pattern ? I did not get that job .

Comment: You may have dodged a bullet here. Insisting on things like design patterns during an interview (especially in vague terms like that) triggers a big red flag for me about the interviewer's (in)competence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well in fact it is overwhelming. There is no simple answer or chosen design patterns. I will begin to apply the "separation of concern" design principle. One class/set of functions only do one thing. That will help to reduce the complexity. Then you can apply structural design patterns. To begin, you can just use delegation.

Before thinking DP, think separation of concern to divide your code in small understandable parts. Then use some DP to link them all.

Do not go looking for situations where to use design patterns, look for code that can be optimised. When you have code that you think is not structured correctly. try to find a design pattern that will solve the problem.

Design patterns are meant to help you solve structural problems, do not go design your application just to be able to use design patterns.